# .NET 4 Threading, Performance Improvement, Parallel Execution - Need

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0

Hi All I am working on performance improvement of a code which has couple of dll.  I want to add parallel execution and improve performance 
values from multiple dlls are put in a function and called from thread 
normal processing takes 0.1 per row
threading takes 1 sec per row

I want to know how can i know that why the thread takes same time like sequential execution ?

Comment: You will need to provide much more information than this - such as how you are launching the threads, or what type of code is in the worker functions.

Comment: If your rows are on a control, it's because the control changes have to occur in the main thread. So you won't see a performance increase. Your calculations can occur on a background thread, but that's it.

Comment: Also, punctuation please. It's one big run-on statement, and I can't determine where your sentences are.

Answer (score 0):

You need to analyze your scenario first to see if it's CPU bound. If there are too much memory allocation, i/o, synchronization, multi-threading is not going to help much.

Try http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28567 for perf analysis.